# is elastic search database contains only structured data?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am a new comer for Elastic search and my question is "I want to store a large amount of log files into Elastic search database. And I am confused with how data files are stored?, which type of files should be stored in the elastic search?, is Elastic search stores only stored structured data files(JSON Format files or some other structure format)? or It will stores unstructured data as well?".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch stores nothing itself, but relies on Apache Lucene for this. Each elasticsearch shard is in itself a fully-functional and independent "index" that can be hosted on any node in the cluster.

https://lucene.apache.org/core/ "Apache LuceneTM is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java."

More about what elasticsearch stores: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-dive-into-elasticsearch-storage

To understand how the data is stored: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html the inverted index:

> Elasticsearch uses a structure called an inverted index, which is
>   designed to allow very fast full-text searches. An inverted index
>   consists of a list of all the unique words that appear in any
>   document, and for each word, a list of the documents in which it
>   appears.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I am not clear with the data format like how to store unstructured data format file. If I have a unstructured log files how to load into elastic search using logstash.

Comment: The API speaks "json", with logstash, your log content should be an object: ``{ "message" : "...." }`` but this is a different topic.